# Transform a DTD in a XSD Schema

Tags: xml, xsd

Are there any tool out there to convert a `DTD` file to a `XSD` one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [this](http://www.hitsw.com/xml_utilites/) online tool.

Answer (score 0):

[XMLPad 3](http://www.wmhelp.com/)

> -- Generation of XML samples from XML schema or a sample of XML Schema from XML file. Converting XSD to DTD and DTD to XSD.

Comment: This is now available from http://wmhelp.com/